Problems with android permissions management
Before start, sorry for my low english level (I'm from Spain), I'll do my best to be undestood.
Im making an app for Android with React Native using Expo, and I really new in it and Android in general. To give some context, my app is kind of social media where you can share locations with a pic to be visited by others. I was making the app using Expo Go getting premissions of location, camera, etc, without problems, but when I build an apk, my app crashes when I go to the components where I ask for permissions. At this point, I know I must indicate in other files the permissions I want, but I don't know how I must do it...
I saw is enough writing permissions in app.json like this:
"android": {
      "permissions": ["CAMERA", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"]

But, in some sites, I saw I must indicate the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml when I do a prebuild. So at this point, I don't know if I must indicate it just in app.json, or AndroidManifest.xml, or both... And I don't know how I must do it.
In a past build, when I logged in everything seems okey, but when I go to the component where I ask for location permissions in code, my app crashed.
In my last build, I expected to see the first component when I log in, but in that moment I add a list of cards that represents the locations shared by other users and you can see the location of them, but now my app crashes here too...
Could someone guide me a bit, please?

It is sufficient to add the permissions in app.json only. Btw, how are you requesting for permission? Could you share that code?

I tried again my app and it seems permissions works with no problems. The core problem is about a MapView component. Where there is a MapView element in a view, my app crashes, but that's different of my original question so... this one could be considered answered.
I made other post about the MapView problem.
